# How can I install ceiling mounted recessed occupancy sensors?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I am looking to replace my current lighting circuit with a motion detector and wondering what is the best way to do this?

I currently have 6 spot lights, controlled by 2 switches on either side of the hallway.
All I want to do is exchange these switches for a ceiling mounted recessed occupancy detector. Can somebody give me details on the safest effective way for this to be done.

Answer (score 1):

There are switches that have motion sensors in them.

There are also Light fixtures that have sensors in them, you would need all new fixtures.
If by spot lights you mean recessed lights this may not work.

We had the switch type in a rental once. I may put them in a hall but never in a main room as every few minutes you had to wave your arms to turn the lights back on. I dont remember how far the sensor could see.

One of these will be the easiest way to add motion sensors, if none of these suits you more info will need to be given about the wiring you wish to change i think.

Do you have a link to the type of device you want to install?

Comment: i had an idea on how this could be completed i just wanted a second oppinion as the existing light swtiches were two way, i managed to connect the sensor to the perminant live and make the switch for said lights obsolete thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to switches with a built-in occupancy/motion sensor, there are wireless occupancy sensor systems designed to easily retrofit existing installations. The sensor is battery-powered and mounted wherever you want, and there's an associated switch that replaces one of your existing switches and talks to the sensor. Because you don't need wires between the sensor and switch, you can simply replace an existing switch (as long as AC power is available in the switch box).

Here's one example:
http://www.lutron.com/en-US/Products/Pages/Sensors/Occupancy-Vacancy/WirelessRadioPowrSavr/Overview.aspx